# Save into multiple tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.net MVC. I am trying to save the data into Order and OrderDetail tables when I click on Save button from my MVC 'Create' page. Are there any examples for this case?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [Movie Database tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-cs).

Comment: It's always updating one table here. I am trying to pass values from View page to controller and save the data into 'order' and 'OrderDetails' tables.

Comment: Well...for saving into multiple tables..just have the respective values passed to your different add_table values method...should be pretty similiar..

Comment: Could you please give an example to pass the data to controller class?

Comment: try this- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/09/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-4-handling-form-edit-and-post-scenarios.aspx